# Slideshow mp4 from jpg files with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Have an command to make slideshow mp4 from *.jpg files:

`ffmpeg -r 1/3 -f concat -safe 0 -i <(ls -v *.jpg | sed "s|^|file '$PWD/|") -vf "scale='min(1920,iw)':min'(1080,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -preset slow -crf 14 slideshow.mp4`

Need good effects from one jpg to another like morphing or just fade in fade out, not just "one picture 3 sec, next picture 3 sec, etc.". Need exactly mp4 video file as result to make possibility to view this on other devices: mediaplayer, tv, smartphone etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research around this problem. Looks like it’s not easy to construct a one line command. Need a script with several steps describing the effects between each individual picture. Something with `-loop 1 -i './01.jpg' -loop 1 -i './02.jpg'` use `filter_complex` and something like `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split=2[stream1out1][stream1out2];[stream2blurred][stream2raw]` step by step.
This is useful [github link](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-video-slideshow-scripts) with slideshow-scripts, e.g. blurred background, fade in/out, zoom in/out.  But this scripts eat many memory, slow generation time, and big mp4 final size.
So looks like initial command not so bad for using as is.